# Java - Android - MyCustomAdapter

Tags: java, android

Hello i have created my own Adapter to make my own customized list view and i have followed a simple tutorial.

When creating my own adapter class i have to override some of the methods

What i dont understand is this :

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int MAX_ITEMS = 64;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SpecialAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MAX_ITEMS;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        }

        TextView large = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        if(position%2 == 0) {
            large.setText("Parne");
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F2F2F2"));
        }
        else{
            large.setText("Neparne");
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A1A1A1"));
        }
    return convertView;
    }
}
```

And in the activity class :

```
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        SpecialAdapter adapter = new SpecialAdapter(getLayoutInflater());
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

### QUESTIONS

- Why do i have to pass the `getLayourInflater()` into the `SpecialAdapter` constructor?
- How does the adapter knows how many rows should it display ? does it get that informations from the `getCount` method automaticaly ?
- If the above question is true is the method `getView` called the `MAX_ITEMS` times? like if it was in a loop ?
- Is the `position` in the `getView` the current loop number out of the `MAX_ITEMS` ?
- what is being passed in the `convertView` ?
- what does the `ViewGroup parent` contains ?

Comment: You don't need to pass an inflater. Typically, you pass a Context, and from that, you get the inflater

Answer (score 1):

According to me this is very customised `adapter` to demonstrate the use of `ListView`.

> Why do i have to pass the getLayourInflater() into the SpecialAdapter
>   constructor?

You need to inflate the layout for your `listview` item so you need `inflater`, so either you have to pass the `inflater` from `constructor` or you have to pass the `context` so that you can create `inflater` in your `adapter` too.

> How does the adapter knows how many rows should it display ? does it
>   get that informations from the getCount method automaticaly ?

you have passed `MAX_ITEMS` in `getCount()` method so it will create 64 items. But note here only those number of items will be created which will fit in a screen at a single time and those views will be recycled as you scroll the `listview`

> If the above question is true is the method getView called the
>   MAX_ITEMS times? like if it was in a loop ?

calling of `getView()` will not be decided on the number of items in `listview`. It will be called as much as times the `listview items` will be rendered while scrolling the `listview`

> is the position in the getView the current loop number out of the
>   MAX_ITEMS ?

Yes position will vary in the range of `0 to MAX_ITEMS - 1`.

> what is being passed in the convertView ?

`convertView` will be the item to be rendered in the `listview`

> what does the ViewGroup parent contains ?

It is the reference to the `listView`

Comment: Your info on rows is wrong-  the adapter will make as many rows as it needs to in order to fill its place on screen, with a max of getCount.  If the screen is filled it will not create more rows, but instead recycle rows between items.

Comment: @GabeSechan I edited my answer. Please feel free to edit my answer. Thanks for pointing out mistake